# Beamer automatic overlay and quote play oddly together

Tags: beamer, overlays, quoting

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<+-|alert@+>]
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
    \begin{quote}
      God doesn't play dice with the world
    \end{quote}
  \item Hello
  \item World
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

that yields:

[image]

As you can notice, the quoted text is treated as an item. For me it seems more natural to expect that when the second item `bar` is uncovered then the quoted text will be uncovered as well (and alerted). After all, `bar` and the text constitute a single item. Are my expectations wrong? How can I obtain the expected behavior?

**BTW:** If you replace `quote` with `center` then the expected behavior is in place...

Comment: IIRC, `quote` uses `list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `quote` in `beamer` is defined as a list which is overlay-aware so your overlay specification for the `itemize` environment will also affecct the ("hidden") `\item` from `quote`; here's the definition from `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`:

```
\newenvironment<>{quote}
{\actionenv#1%
  \usebeamertemplate{quote begin}%
  \usebeamerfont{quote}%
  \usebeamercolor{quote}%
  \list{}{\rightmargin   \leftmargin}
\item\relax}
{\endlist\usebeamertemplate{quote end}\endactionenv}
```

If you want to have an environment similar in all aspects to `quote`, but with no overlay-awareness, you could use

```
\newenvironment{myquote}
{%
  \usebeamertemplate{quote begin}%
  \usebeamerfont{quote}%
  \usebeamercolor{quote}%
  \list{}{\rightmargin   \leftmargin}
\item\relax}
{\endlist\usebeamertemplate{quote end}}
```

A complete example

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{myquote}
{%
  \usebeamertemplate{quote begin}%
  \usebeamerfont{quote}%
  \usebeamercolor{quote}%
  \list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}
\item\relax}
{\endlist\usebeamertemplate{quote end}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<+-|alert@+>]
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
    \begin{quote}
      God doesn't play dice with the world
    \end{quote}
  \item Hello
  \item World
  \end{itemize}

  \begin{itemize}[<+-|alert@+>]
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
    \begin{myquote}
      God doesn't play dice with the world
    \end{myquote}
  \item Hello
  \item World
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to manually correct the `beamerpauses` counter, which can be done using the overlay specification for `quote` with the "dot" modifier `<.->`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<+-|alert@+>]
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
    \begin{quote}<.->
      God doesn't play dice with the world
    \end{quote}
  \item Hello
  \item World
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

or manually:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<+-|alert@+>]
  \item Foo
  \item Bar\addtocounter{beamerpauses}{-1}
    \begin{quote}
      God doesn't play dice with the world
    \end{quote}
  \item Hello
  \item World
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```